# JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly but build is successful and the script works fine in Jmeter GUI and cmd prompt

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, environment-variables, load-testing

I have created a jmeter jmx script and it is getting executed perfectly in GUI and non GUI mode. I have configured the same in Jenkins but I am getting the build success with an error message as "The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program"

I have also tried setting the JMETER_HOME as E:\apache-jmeter-4.0 in User variables and Path as E:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin in System Variables and it didn't work.

I tried the below Questions but no luck.

['jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890296/jmeter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

[JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882280/jmeter-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined)

Here is my command and error from jenkins

E:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\jmeter -jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t E:\JMeter Tutorial\JenkinsIntegration.jmx -l E:\JMeter Tutorial\JenkinsIntegrationResult.jtl

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have also added .bat after the jmeter in cmd line and it dint help E:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\jmeter.bat -jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t E:\JMeter Tutorial\JenkinsIntegration.jmx -l E:\JMeter Tutorial\JenkinsIntegrationResult.jtl

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of setting an environment variable is defining it under Manage Jenkins - Configure System - Global properties:

[image]

The better way would be using [Environment Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) plugin

And last but not the least, you're getting this message because you're sitting at outdated JMeter 4.0, if you upgrade to i.e. [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) you won't be seeing this warning, moreover according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so in any case upgrade does make sense, check out what is the [latest stable JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) version and switch to it

Comment: used the latest jmeter E:\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t E:\JMeter Tutorial\JenkinsIntegration.jmx -l E:\JMeter Tutorial\JenkinsIntegrationResult.jtl   and java 1,8.0_251 and jre 1.8.0_241

Answer (score 0):

I removed Jenkins and reinstalled as well as i deleted the old job and created a new job with default settings in jenkins (i dint do anything in the manage Jenkins) and it worked charm with both jmerer 4.0 and 5.3. java 1.8.0_251

[image]

with 5.3 
[image]

with 4.0
[image]

as far i remember i just removed the space and added underscore in the below command from folder name  JMeter Tutorial to Jmeter_Tutorial

E:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>E:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t E:\JMeter_Tutorial\JenkinsIntegration.jmx -l E:\JMeter_Tutorial\JenkinsIntegrationResult.csv